# Stripe public URL to receipt

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there a public URL to a receipt, given a transaction id? For example:

`https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/ch_8In0hTNkSQliCq`

This requires a login. Is there any way I can get a permalink to a receipt? I'd like to be able to email it to a customer, or present on an order confirmation page (or anything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time this question was asked (and this answer was initially written), this wasn't possible. However, since then, Stripe has added the `receipt_url` parameter to the Charge object: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_url.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible by recovering the load with the parameter "receipt_url"

API link:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve

Answer (score 0):

You can get a receipt url from `Charge` object. It is not a pdf url, but a public charge page where you have a download link to both invoice and receipt files.

Here is my approach with PHP:

```
$invoiceId = '...';
$invoice = Invoice::retrieve($invoiceId);
// return invoice pdf if not paid
if (!$invoice->charge) return $invoice->invoice_pdf;

$charge = Charge::retrieve($invoice->charge);
// return receipt url if paid
return $charge->receipt_url;
```